# Core Data, display to-many relationship distinctly along with aggregate count

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm beginner in Core Data, so trying to wrap my mind around the following.

Let's say I have the following model:

```
   Kid (1) -> (M) ToyName (car)
                  ToyAttributes (1) -> (M) key (color), value (black)
                                           key (price), value (20)
                                           key (store), value (toys r us)
```

ToyAttributes has 3 key/value pairs.

What I want to do is list the colors distinctly.  So, if other toys are black also, I want to display black only once.

Another nice thing to do would be to display the aggregate count of how many black toys we have.

I currently have the following:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kid" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];
```

But unsure how to structure the proper KVC to find the proper key=color and get those values for every kid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set inverse relationship on your Entity, then if you use an `NSPredicate` to fetch the black one you will be able to follow the inverse relationship to retrieve the desired ToyName.

You minimally want to read those :
[Fetching Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html)
[Predicate Format String Syntax](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1)

---

This is some old code I've got, not perfect and not exactly what you are looking for, but still an example of the use of a `NSPredicate`.
This is a simple `NSFetchRequest` that will return all kListe entity ordered in some way.

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)requestPourListe{

NSFetchRequest *resultat = nil;

NSEntityDescription *description4Liste = 
[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kListe 
            inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
resultat = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[resultat setEntity:description4Liste];
[resultat setSortDescriptors:self.sortDescriptorsPourNom];
//  Si on veut faire un Fetch plus petit en mémoire (Partial Fault)
//[resultat setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:kNom]];
return [resultat autorelease];
}
// Now time to use that request get the request
NSFetchRequest *requet4Liste = FRUtile.requestPourListe;
    NSError *monErreur = nil;
      // And Use it agains a NSManagedObjecContext (moc)
    NSArray *lesListes = [moc executeFetchRequest:requet4Liste
                                            error:&monErreur];
```

In the folloing `self.list` is one of the NSManagedObject that was fetch with the preceding request.

```
// those NSSet are set that were return from a simple relationship query
// so those set contain NSManagedObject
NSSet *desListeItems = self.liste.listeItems;
// HERE I'm fetching the relationship kRelationPrixElement on all NSManagedObject
// present in the set desListeItems (one to one relationShip)
NSSet *desPrixElements = [desListeItems valueForKey:kRelationPrixElement];
// generate the path, traverse the relationship call kRelationCommerce and 
// reach it's attribute name kNom
NSString *predicateKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", kRelationCommerce, kNom];
// get an array out of one set probably not necessary
NSArray *desPrixElementsAR = [desPrixElements allObjects];
NSMutableArray *lesPrixAAfficher = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (NSString *value in self.commercesNoms) {
            // in a predicate with format %K MUST be the key or keyPath and 
            // %@ MUST be the value you are searching for
            // the predicate here is done agains a many-to-one relation
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K MATCHES %@)", predicateKey, value];
            // Now I'm applying the predicate to the array
    [lesPrixAAfficher addObjectsFromArray:[desPrixElementsAR filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

There is a thing that you must take into account while designing your model and your fetch request, you can follow relationship in a keyPath throughout many Entities AS LONG AS those relationship are `to one` relationship.
You can't use a keyPath to traverse a to-many relation, because how could Core Data know which of the entity it should follow on.
And finally when you got an NSManagedObject you can use dot notation on it to retreive it's properties and relationships.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to query for a specific key in a child element.  Do you a have code example?

Comment: @Maverick some code example, if you have some french notion it will help to follow / understand the variable names.